A question on Beck's theorem in Mac Lane's reference
When I read Beck's theorem in the book "Categories for the Working Mathematcian(second edition)", I don't understand why the functor M is uniquely defined on arrows in the corresponding lemma on Page 153:

Now I see that. Given f : a' -> b' in A'
consider this commutative diagram

apply functor M we get the following diagram

Then M(f) is uniquely defined since $k_b$ is a coequalizer.

Well I guess this lies in the definition of 'generate split equalizer' or in some book 'strictly generate equalizer'. As shown in page 151 of your reference, it says '..., moreover this unique arrow is the equalizer of $f$ and $g$.' I guess probably you ignore this condition.
Thus in the diagram of the lemma you referred $Ma'$ is also a equalizer.

And for any morphism $a'\rightarrow b'$, we have the diagram shown in your reference,

Then $Mf$ is unique because by the universal property of $Ma'$ as a coequalizer, composition of arrows $FG'F'G'a'\rightrightarrows FG'a'\stackrel{FG'f}{\longrightarrow} FG'b'\stackrel{k_{b}}{\longrightarrow} Mb'$ admits a unique factorization through $Ma'$, which is $Mf$, it is unique by universal property.
In most cases, we don't need such strong 'creating equalizer condition' as required in Mac Lane's book, if we drop the unique requirement for the lift of the equalizer, then the 'isomorphism of categories' become 'equivalence of categories', which is good enough in ordinary cases.

Thank you! Now I see that. Given arrow f : a' -> b' in A', this arrow can be view as a T-algebra morphism, since M is a functor , it must preserve the commutative diagram(The bottom commutative diagram you provide is just apply M to some diagram), and Mf must be uniquely definied by those coequalizers.

@bobi At worst one might have that it's defined up to a unique natural isomorphism compatible with the other data, since the coequaliser is only defined up to (appropriately unique) isomorphism
